# ng2charts using borderColor with array value

Tags: javascript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to draw a line chart with individual colors per data entry. 
  Using borderColor as an array of colors should have achieved desired behaviour but doesn't seem to work.

**Did anyone else encounter this problem? Are there any easy workarounds?**

**Code used:**

```
 public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81], label: 'Series A' },
  ];
  public lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'];
  public lineChartOptions: (ChartOptions & { annotation: any }) = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  public lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      borderColor: ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
    },
  ];
  public lineChartLegend = true;
  public lineChartType = 'line';
```

**Output:**
[Broken chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XYbV.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to have different line colors between the data points. This can be done by [extending](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types) an existing line chart as shown in this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-js-multicolorline). Note that this approach doesn't use `ng2-charts`.

A simpler and probably better suited solution would be to use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) `afterLayout` hook. In there, you can create a linear gradient through [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient).

```
lineChartPlugins = [{
  afterLayout: chart => {
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
    var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xAxis.right, 0);
    var dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
    dataset.colors.forEach((c, i) => {
      var stop = 1 / (dataset.colors.length - 1) * i;
      gradientStroke.addColorStop(stop, dataset.colors[i]);
    });
    dataset.backgroundColor = gradientStroke;
    dataset.borderColor = gradientStroke;
    dataset.pointBorderColor = gradientStroke;
    dataset.pointBackgroundColor = gradientStroke;
    dataset.pointHoverBorderColor = gradientStroke;
    dataset.pointHoverBackgroundColor = gradientStroke;
  }
}];
```

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-gradient-multicolorline?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-js-gradient-multicolorline?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) shows an example that doesn't use `ng2-charts`.